# A conditional statement in Button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to ReactJs, I have this button called "Add Item" that I would like to disable if a certain condition is reached. Basically I would to pass an if and else statement in the button. However I am stuck as to how to do it.

```
const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);
var quantity = 11;

<Button
            if ( quantity > 10 ){ setDisable(true) } // don't know how to properly build here

            title="Add Item"
            buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: PrimaryColor, borderRadius: 10}}
            titleStyle={{fontSize:13}} 
            disabled={disable}   
            onPress={InsertItem}                     
          />
```

Any assist is kindly appreciated

Comment: Can you show where `quantity` comes from?

Comment: If it's hard-coded to 11, what's the point of the `if`? Show your *actual* code?

Comment: edited my post. "quantity" is just a variable I declared as 11 to test code and disable the button if it is >10. Apology for the misunderstand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to add any condition like this `if ( quantity > 10 ){ setDisable(true) }` then do it in `onPress`
2. or you can useEffect with dependency variable so that it invokes every time there is any change in that variable

```js
     React.useEffect(() => {
        if (quantity > 10) {
          setDisable(true)
        }
      }, [quantity])
```

3. or simply just add a condition for disable in the `disabled` tag of `Button` like this `disabled={quantity > 10}` so whenever your quantity is greater than 10 it will return true and it will be the same as `disabled={true}` and same goes for when the condition is false

```js
    const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);
    var quantity = 11;
    
       <Button
        title="Add Item"
        buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: PrimaryColor, borderRadius: 10}}
        titleStyle={{fontSize:13}} 
        disabled={quantity > 10}
        onPress={InsertItem}                     
       />
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to have disabled stored as a state. If `quantity` is a prop or inside the state of your component, it's probably just sufficient to have a calculated value:

`<Button disabled={quantity > 10} .... />`